# Understanding a reentrant parent function that waits on a child process in a non-blocking manner

Tags: process, fork, c++14, nonblocking, waitpid

I have some C++ code running on Linux in which a re-entrant, bool returning, parent process forks a child process (of course only once), and then uses waitpid to check the exit status of said child process. If the child process is complete then it returns to the parent process and then the child exits, and then the parent process sees this exit status and returns true (and then moves on to other code).

Otherwise if the child process is still running the parent process will see this as well and return false, and then the parent process gets called over and over again until child process finishes and exits.

So in other words, the parent process calls waitpid with WNOHANG and thus waits for the child in a non-blocking manner.

The term "wait" is a bit of a misnomer here as the parent function does not wait for the child to complete before returning; however the parent will not stop getting called until the child is finished.

so something like:

```
main()
{
    while(status != true)
    {
        status = funcThatCallsFork();
    }
    // child completed and parent saw exit status and is moving on now
}

bool funcThatCallsFork()
{
    //if first pass
    fork()

    //child code (pid == 0)
    {
        funcThatChildCalls();
        _exit(); // child exits as soon as it returns from call
    }

    //else not first pass
    //check waitpid with WNOHANG for status change of child

    //if child exited return true, else return false 
}

funcThatChildCalls()
{
    // do time consuming stuff

    // return
}
```

My question is, since the child process was spawned on parent process frame #1, and by the time that the child process is finished the parent process will now be on some frame # (1+n); then how does the child process know to return to the current parent process frame, and not the parent process frame from which it was spawned (i.e: frame #1)? Indeed it does based on testing I've performed; just trying to understand why.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.  Processes don't "return" to one another.  Please show some real code that exhibits what you're talking about.

Comment: You can't call a process.